# Project configuration not showing in Visual studio 2019 (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I've opened my Xamarin Forms project (originally created in VS Mac) in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows.

I've got 3 Projects (App, App.iOS, App.Android). I had created some additional build configurations (Debug-Staging, Release-Staging and Debug-Prod, Release-Prod).

However, when opening in VS 2019, I can only see the standard Debug and Release configurations for the Shared App Project. (additional release configs seem to be there for the iOS and Android ones).

Any ideas how to resolve this?

[image: Configurations]

[image]

If I click New and add Release-Prod, the dropdown for my shared project doesn't update..

Comment: "*If I click New and add Release-Prod, the dropdown for my shared project doesn't update.*" It works in my visual studio(`16.8.3`). Whether the version of vs for mac and vs for pc all is the latest version?

Comment: Windows Visual studio 2019 is Version 16.8.3. On the Mac it is 8.7.9 (build 9).

Comment: Okey, it's strange. You could share the sample Mac forms project link here, I will check that in local site.